# TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'rxjs'

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, rxjs, rxjs7

I have upgraded my Angular App dependency and successfully installed them. Unfortunately I am now unable to use 'rxjs'. Below is the error returned by the IDE.

> TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'rxjs'.'C:/Path/to/project/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/rxjs` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'rxjs';

Below is my `package.json`

```json
{
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.15.4",
    "npm": "7.11.2"
  },
  "name": "furaha-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "serve": "ng serve",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build --prod --aot",
    "test": "ng test",
    "test-coverage": "ng test --code-coverage",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "lint-fix": "npm run lint --fix",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "snyk-protect": "snyk protect",
    "prepare": "npm run snyk-protect"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1102.9",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.11",
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.12",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.11",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.12",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.12",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.1102.11",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.12",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^11.2.12",
    "@dimakorotkov/tinymce-mathjax": "^1.0.7",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngrx/component": "^11.1.1",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^11.1.1",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^11.1.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^11.1.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^11.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-angular": "^4.2.2",
    "@types/mathjax": "0.0.36",
    "@types/pouchdb": "^6.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "flag-icon-css": "^3.5.0",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.19",
    "mathjax": "^3.1.4",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^6.4.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "ngx-duration-picker": "^3.2.0",
    "ngx-mathjax": "0.0.13",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pouchdb": "^7.2.2",
    "quagga": "^0.12.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.0.0",
    "snyk": "^1.574.0",
    "tinymce": "^5.7.1",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.1.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^4.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^4.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^4.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^4.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~11.2.12",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^11.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.6.10",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^15.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.22.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.22.0",
    "eslint": "^7.25.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "33.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.7.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "7.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "karma-verbose-reporter": "0.0.6",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1"
  },
  "snyk": true
}
```

On running `ng serve` I receive several errors related to types in `rxje` e.g in the below

```
this.genders$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectGenders));
```

> property 'pipe' does not exist on Store

```
this.teacherProfile$ = this.route.parent?.paramMap
      .pipe(map(params => Number(params.get('id'))))
      .pipe(tap(id => this.teacherId = id))
      .pipe(mergeMap((id) => this.store.pipe(select(selectTeacher(id)))));
```

> Object 'params' is of type unknown

Is it possible to use rxjs v7 in an Angular v11 app?

Answer (score 10):

> Is it possible to use rxjs v7 in an Angular v11 app?

no.
see the related github issue =>
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/41897