# RXJS 7 - TS2693: 'AjaxDirection' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs7

I upgraded my angular 11 projects `RxJS 7` and in web storm it suggested me to change some `Subject` imports, Once I update these imports I am getting below error

```
ERROR: node_modules/rxjs/dist/types/internal/ajax/types.d.ts:9:40 - error TS1110: Type expected.

9 export declare type AjaxResponseType = `${AjaxDirection}_${ProgressEventType}`;
                                         ~~~
node_modules/rxjs/dist/types/internal/ajax/types.d.ts:9:43 - error TS2693: 'AjaxDirection' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

9 export declare type AjaxResponseType = `${AjaxDirection}_${ProgressEventType}`;
                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/rxjs/dist/types/internal/ajax/types.d.ts:9:60 - error TS2693: 'ProgressEventType' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

9 export declare type AjaxResponseType = `${AjaxDirection}_${ProgressEventType}`;
                                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

An unhandled exception occurred: node_modules/rxjs/dist/types/internal/ajax/types.d.ts:9:40 - error TS1110: Type expected.
```

anyone resolved this issue of tried to migrate to `RxJs7`?

Comment: Angular is not ready for rxjs 7. You should roll back until it is.

Comment: thanks @R.Richards for the quick response

Comment: Keep in mind that RxJS 7 requires TS 4.2. What version of TS are you using?

Comment: I am using typescript 4.0.5, may be that is the reason

Comment: @AniruddhaDas I'm quite confident that's the reason, have a look at the first bullet point: https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/breaking-changes

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67350362/3297680

Comment: Thanks to @R.Richards answer.
It should be a warning when installing rxjs on the angular environment.